# How to pass a record from ssrs main report dataset to subreport

Tags: reporting-services, report

I have a customer dataset from a main report which I bind to a list. In this list I have a subreport. How do I pass the each row of data to the subreport? I don't want to pass an id from main report to subreport then call a stored procedure to fetch the record based on the id. I already have all the details flattened out in the dataset which i fetched from the main report.

Answer (score 1):

The fact is that you can't pass a set of rows as a parameter to a subreport. The most common approach is to have a shared dataset so you can execute it again based on the same parameters or a store procedure for exactly the same purpose. Only other thing can be done, and it's to convert a dataset's field into a string containing all the values, and then split it again. This is done with SSRS built-in functions join and split (if I'm not wrong), but to be honest I don't know if that solves your problem and it's a really nightmare to get it working properly. 
My standard approach is to have efficient stored procedures that can be executed any times within a set of SSRS reports. I understand that you want to retrieve each datataset only once, but SSRS is not meant to make that easy.
And even more important, if you queries or procedures are efficient, data retrieval time is just a tiny porting of all SSRS report build and presentation time. Usually rendering the report is what takes longer and some repeated data extraction won't be noticed in the overall execution.

If you what to be really efficient in data retrieving, you can explore the options provided to cache data in datasets, but stills seems to be too complex to solve something that doesn't really need a solution.

Hope this helps.